# Unlocking a user while impersonating to a user with priviliges

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

I am trying to unlock a user while impersonating to a user with priviliges in active directory to unlock users in a sepcific group.

I'm using `LogonUser` from `advapi32.dll` to logon the user, after impersonating and using using{} I'm printing the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` - and it does not show the name of the computer, it shows the name of the user I tryed to impersonate to - meaning that the impersonation succeeded (?)

Then I'm using the `UnlockAccount` method within the `UserPrincipal` presenting the user I want to unlock - and I get a strange error saying - "Operating Errors Occured" - with no inner exception that can help me trace the real error...

---

I created a class according to a solution I saw in one of the questions here, thats manages the impersonation with logonuser method and the stuff it needs. The main code goes like this :

```
using (Impersonation mp = Impersonation.LogonUser(username, domain, pass, 
       LogonType.Network))
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(Impersonation.UserToken);
    WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();
    Console.WriteLine("Logged in with : " +
                      WindowsIdentity.GetCurrrent().Name);
    // To do is the method that unlocks the user - get as parameter
    // the UserPrincipal Object to unlock
    bSuccess = toDo(uspUsserPrinc);
}
```

Can someone recognize the issue?

Comment: Please tag this as Windows, as well as whatever programming language you're using. Also, this wall of text is not very inviting to readers.

Comment: I informed you that it's a bit tricky to shoe the code, and i'll tag

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Tried to pretty up a bit the question + updated the tags

Comment: I'm not sure whether the Active Directory API supports impersonation.  You might need to launch a subprocess as the privileged user instead.

Comment: @HarryJohn Do you have an idea how can I do that ?

Comment: I tried to launch a process through the program after I made the impersonation. The role of the process is to unlock the wanted user - but I still get the same error and the user still locked.